# Select option from Internet Explorer dropdown list

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am working on opening a webpage and filling out some fields. I managed to fill textboxes, but I am having trouble selecting options from drop down lists checking/selecting radio buttons.

This is the HTML code referring to the dropdown list:

[HTML code for drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAI3U.jpg)

This one is the code for one of the radio buttons:
[HTML code for radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDJf.jpg)

This is my code so far:

```
Sub w()
'
' w Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
'pick ups cell b2 value
Dim cellvalue As String
cellvalue = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
''Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = cellvalue '
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

'fill email response address
HTMLDoc.all.emailAddresses.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3)

'fill shipment reference number
HTMLDoc.all.filingRefNumber.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 7)

'fill dropbox option
'NOT WORKING    
If Not VBA.IsNull(ie.document.getElementById("select2-drop-mask")) Then
    Dim htmlSelect
    Set htmlSelect = ie.document.getElementById("select2-drop-mask")
    htmlSelect.Value = 4 - POSTDEPARTURE
Else
    MsgBox "Element 'select2-drop-mask' was not found", vbExclamation
End If  

'SELECT RADIO BUTTON
' NOT WORKING
ie.document.getElementsByName("shipmentInfo.routedExpTransactionInd.stringFiEld").Item(1).Checked = True

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("Login")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "Login" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
'Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your list/dropdown, I think there are two potential solutions.

1. Change to

   htmlSelect.Value = "4 - POSTDEPARTURE"
2. Refer to the index value.  I.e. if it's the first item in the dropdown, it's item(0).

   htmlSelect.item(0).selected="True"

For your radio button, wrap 'true' in quotes.  Also you'd need to loop through all elements with that particular name (getElementbyID only returns 1 item, but getElementsByName can refer to multiple elements).

e.g.

```
dim objects
dim obj

set objects=document.getElementsByName("shipmentInfo.routedExpTransactionInd.stringFiEld")

for each obj in objects
obj.item(0).checked=True
next
```

or try:

```
 Set ieRadio = IE.Document.all
    ieRadio.Item("shipmentInfo.routedExpTransactionInd.stringFiEld")(1).Checked = True
```

Comment: Thank you RyanL, it is working now! I dont have much experience with loops but I managed to make it work.